# Xamarin forms create table

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to create a table, using list view in xamarin forms. I am able to create list view with five columns. But I can't able to give header for the columns and lines. If anyone know how to create the table structure with headers please help me. Thanks in advance.

This is my source code for table[Header and Listview]

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Padding="40,10,10,40" Spacing="0">
        <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Black"></BoxView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="40">
            <BoxView WidthRequest="1" HeightRequest="10" BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Fill" />
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                <controls:CheckBox></controls:CheckBox>
                <Label Text="Select All" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <BoxView WidthRequest="1" HeightRequest="10" BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Fill" />
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                <Label Text="Last Name, First Name" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                <Button Text=">" HeightRequest="5" WidthRequest="5"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
            <BoxView WidthRequest="1" HeightRequest="10" BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Fill" />
            <Label Text="Child ID" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
            <BoxView WidthRequest="1" HeightRequest="10" BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Fill" />
            <Label Text="Date of Birth" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
            <BoxView WidthRequest="1" HeightRequest="10" BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Fill" />
            <Label Text="Location" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
            <BoxView WidthRequest="1" HeightRequest="10" BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Fill" />
            <Label Text="Enrollment" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
            <BoxView WidthRequest="1" HeightRequest="10" BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Fill" />
            <Label Text="Actions" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
            <BoxView WidthRequest="1" HeightRequest="10" BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Fill" />
        </StackLayout>
        <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Black"></BoxView>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Padding="40,10,10,40" HeightRequest="200" Grid.Row="1" Spacing="0">
    <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding ChildRecords}" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout>
                                <!-- <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Black"></BoxView>-->
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <BoxView WidthRequest="1" HeightRequest="15" BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">

                                    <Label Text="Select All" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <BoxView WidthRequest="1" HeightRequest="15" BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Start"  />
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                    <Label Text="Last Name, First Name" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                                    <Button Text=">" HeightRequest="5" WidthRequest="5"></Button>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <BoxView WidthRequest="1"  BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="15" />
                                <Label Text="Child ID" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                                <BoxView WidthRequest="1"  BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="15" />
                                <Label Text="Date of Birth" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                                <BoxView WidthRequest="1"  BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="15" />
                                <Label Text="Location" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                                <BoxView WidthRequest="1"  BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="15" />
                                <Label Text="Enrollment" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                                <BoxView WidthRequest="1"  BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="15" />
                                <Label Text="Actions" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                                <BoxView WidthRequest="1"  BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="15"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Black"></BoxView>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! There's several ways of doing this, and the best solution would be to build off what you already have. Could you please share the code of your table with us? If you could also add some screenshots to better understand what you have and what you are trying to get to

Comment: Hi, I edited my post for what i am trying to do. The Header column and Listview Column widths are mismatching. And i am using boxview for lines it also not working as expected. It would be great if you provide a solution for that. Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful for you to add the namespace information. I'm not sure what assembly "controls" comes from. Code for the entire page would be even more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically what I like to do is create a Grid above the ListView for a Header, and then create ViewCells containing Grids within the ListView with the same column widths.

As an example:

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" RowSpacing="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="Heading 1" />
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="Heading 2" />
        <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="Heading 3" />
    </Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{}" HasUnevenRows="true" HeightRequest="200" SeparatorVisibility="None">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <Grid Margin="0" Padding="0" RowSpacing="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Margin="0" Text="{Binding data1}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Margin="0" Text="{Binding data2}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Margin="0" Text="{Binding data3}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Note also the ListView comes with a Header, which is useful if you want the header to scroll with the items in the ListView. Have a look at this documentation: [Customizing ListView Appearance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a quick/professional looking way, you can try Synfucion [DataGrid](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfdatagrid/getting-started) custom control for Xamarin. They are free to use if your company earn less than 1 millions.

Comment: Not entirely true. I spoke with Syncfusion and if I make some software which I sell to a company, I can't use Syncfusion for free if my client (who receive the software) earns more than 1 milion.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Grid for that purpose make the first row of the grid as the header, you can easily change the style on the header only. Here is the sample yo create 3 rows and two column

```
<Grid>  
<Grid.RowDefinitions>  
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />  
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />  
    <RowDefinition Height="*" /> 
</Grid.RowDefinitions>  
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />  
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> 
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just edited my post with source code what i am trying to do. If you know a solution for that please tell.

Comment: @Tulasi to match with header you must use grid inside listview too. use grid to make columns too. use grid and place label inside that

Answer (score 0):

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" RowSpacing="0" >

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="Entry Name" BackgroundColor="LightGreen" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="Entry Date" BackgroundColor="LightGreen" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" />
        <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="Enty Type" BackgroundColor="LightGreen" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" />
        <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="Transaction Type"  BackgroundColor="LightGreen" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        <Label Grid.Column="4" Text="Cashflow " BackgroundColor="LightGreen" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" />
        <Label Grid.Column="5" Text="Particular" BackgroundColor="LightGreen" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" />
        <Label Grid.Column="6" Text="VoucherNumber" BackgroundColor="LightGreen" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" />
        <Label Grid.Column="7" Text="LedgerFolio" BackgroundColor="LightGreen" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" />
        <Label Grid.Column="8" Text="Amount" BackgroundColor="LightGreen" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" />
        <Label Grid.Column="9" Text="PurchaseInvoice" BackgroundColor="LightGreen" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" />
        <Label Grid.Column="10" Text="Credit Or Debit" BackgroundColor="LightGreen" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold"/>



        <ListView x:Name="ContentListview" HasUnevenRows="true" HeightRequest="200" SeparatorVisibility="None" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="11" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Default" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Default">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <Grid Margin="0" Padding="0" RowSpacing="0">

                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding EntryName}"  TextColor="Black" />
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding EntryDate}"  TextColor="Black"  />
                                <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding EntyType}"  TextColor="Black"  />
                                <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding TransactionType}"   TextColor="Black" />
                                <Label Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Cashflow}"  TextColor="Black"  />
                                <Label Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding Particular}"  TextColor="Black"  />
                                <Label Grid.Column="6" Text="{Binding VoucherNumber}"  TextColor="Black"  />
                                <Label Grid.Column="7" Text="{Binding LedgerFolio}"  TextColor="Black"  />
                                <Label Grid.Column="8" Text="{Binding Amount}"  TextColor="Black"  />
                                <Label Grid.Column="9" Text="{Binding PurchaseInvoice}"  TextColor="Black"  />
                                <Label Grid.Column="10" Text="{Binding CreditOrDebit}"  TextColor="Black" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>


    </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

This is what I did, and the picture below is its outcome.[Xamarin form result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWlgl.png). Sorry, cannot show my code behind.